# Communicating between C++ and Remote Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, ipc

I have a c++ program running on a server. I'd like to control the program from a web page.

Unfortunately, this is new territory for me, and I think I may have stumbled down the wrong path. What I've done so far is create an IPC between my program and a CGI script. When the user loads the web page, the cgi script runs, queries my main app for some data, and then creates some javascript code -- namely it populates some variables, which another js file reads, and uses to display the page properly.

This seems to work, but now I want to update the web page at periodic intervals (say every two minutes or so). I'm wondering if I should abandon what I have and implement some sort of socket communication between the two. My alternative is to rerun the cgi script and dynamically reload the variables.

I'm wondering if this would be considered a kludge...  (Again, not overly familiar with javascript, so unfortunately I don't have a good sense of what's considered good or bad practice).

Comment: Sounds like it would be safest to implement sockets (or regular old ajax communication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating a web page periodically can be done several ways:

1. From your web page, you can send a periodic Ajax call to the CGI server to get updated data.  When that data is returned, you can use Javascript to put that newer data into the displayed web page.
2. You can make a webSocket connection from your web page to a server.  Once that webSocket connection is established, the server can directly send new data to the client whenever appropriate.  The client, when receiving the new data, can then use Javascript to insert it into the displayed web page.

The webSocket connection option is generally considered more efficient because communication only happens between client and server when the server actually has some new data.  It also provides lower latency to show changes and provides more efficient bandwidth usage since no requests are made from client to server when there is nothing new on the server.

To implement a server-side webSocket connection, you will need something besides a CGI script because a webSocket connection is persistent.  You will also want to work on improving the notification between your C++ program and whatever process is running the webSocket connection so you are doing something efficient there too.

Comment: Thanks.   I wasn't aware of what AJAX was, but now that I've read up on it, it sounds like a good fit.   In my particular case, it's very simple for me to adapt what I have to work with AJAX (plus there will always be new data every two minutes, so I'll have to make the call anyways).